# SIGINT ignored while calling system(3)

Tags: c++, linux

I have a process with a thread that calls for example: `system("ping -qnc 1 192.168.1.1")` in a loop.
When I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>, SIGINT is ignored as per the documentation:

> During execution of the command, `SIGCHLD` will be blocked, and `SIGINT` and
>   `SIGQUIT` will be ignored, in the process that calls `system()` (these signals will be handled according to their defaults inside the child process that executes *command*).

Why is this, and what can I do to exit my process with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process has those signals blocked so that when the user presses Ctrl-C `ping` will be killed without your program also being killed.

If you *want* your program to be killed you can check `system()`'s return value and see if `ping` was killed due to a signal. If it was you can take appropriate action.

```
int status = system("ping -qnc 1 192.168.1.1");

if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    std::cout << "ping exited with exit code " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << std::endl;
}
else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    std::cerr << "ping killed by signal " << WTERMSIG(status) << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
else {
    std::cerr << "ping exited for some other reason" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but I cannot help but feel like this is a hack. I do not understand why the child process is signaled, as the user is not even aware there is another process running. He presses ctrl+c to exit the parent. Anyway, would peopen() behave the same?

Comment: Plus, in my case, I will have several threads that might be stuck in a system() call. Will all of the children get signaled?

Comment: Ctrl-C sends the signal to all processes in the foreground process group.

Answer (score 2):

[POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html#tag_16_597_03) remarks that `system()` call 'need not be thread-safe'.

Generally speaking, calling `system()` in a multithread environment is not a good idea. The purpose of the function is like "run a secondary process and wait for it to finish". That's why the signals are trapped and blocked.

If you expect your main process to be killed somehow (eg. by pressing Ctrl+C) perhaps you would prefer to use `popen()` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, peopen() was also on my mind, but I don't need IO so I went with system(). Yes, I would like to gracefully exit the process and do some cleanup.

Comment: I concur with this. `system()` is pretty lackluster. It's kind of like `scanf()`: fine for a quick program but I wouldn't use it in production code.

Comment: If you don't care of the output of the second process, you could just use the good ol' `fork/exec` pair (pretty straightforward if you don't care about the child's fate).

Answer (score 0):

To conclude, `popen` works ok as long as you explicitly discard the command output (`cmd > /dev/null`) or read the output before `pclose`, but I eventually went with `boost::process::system()` which uses `execve` and does not trap the `SIGINT` either:

```cpp
bool ping(const std::string& ip,
          uint32_t count = 1,
          std::chrono::seconds timeout = 1s)
(
    return (0 ==
    bp::system(bp::exe = "/bin/ping",
               bp::args = { "-q", 
                            "-w", std::to_string(timeout.count()),
                            "-c", std::to_string(count),
                            ip },
               bp::std_out > bp::null));
}
```

The only "advantage" of `popen`, was that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> would also signal the child, as with system, but without trapping the signal. In my case I actually want to wait for the child to complete normally.